# Server tag error when passing parameters to javascript from gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, parameters

I have a gridview and need to pass two parameters to a javascript function when pressing a button in the gridview.
The script is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function AddItem(name,price) {

            javascript: simpleCart.add('name=' + name, 'price=' + price, 'quantity=1');
        }    
    </script>
```

In the gridview I tried passing the parameters like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" OnClientClick="AddItem('<%# Eval("Name") %>', '<%# Eval("Price") %>')" />
```

But got a 'Server tag is not well formed error'.

I also tried like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Name","Price", "return AddItem({0},{1})") %>'  />
```

But the Eval function only seems to allow the passing of 1 parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" 
     OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Name", "AddItem(\"{0}\", ").ToString() + Eval("Price", "\"{0}\")").ToString() %>' />
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, been stuck forever! Do you mind explaining why yours worked when the others didn't? Thanks again

Comment: It's works because each single quote disorientate markup parser. Except this one, expression evaluated practically the same way as regular C# expression.

Comment: That's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" OnClientClick='<%# "AddItem('" + Eval("Name") + "', '" + Eval("Price") + "')"' />
```

or this also might work

```
<asp:Button ID="AddCartButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" onClick="AddCartButton_Click" OnClientClick="AddItem('<%# Eval(&quot;Name&quot;) %>', '<%# Eval(&quot;Price&quot;) %>')" />
```

using quotes inside a server control attributes upsets the compilation process as it can't figure out where the attribute ends. You can either use apostrophes (1st example) or escape the quotes (2nd example)

Comment: The first solution still gives me a server tag error (I'm assuming there was a mistake at the end and changed it to )"%>' )

The second one doesn't work either, it passes <%# Eval("Name")%> as a parameter :/